# Lombook @Data not allowing object to printed if it is extend from collections

Tags: lombok

I have an object which is extended from an ArrayList.
Here is the code:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class MyObject extends ArrayList<ParentObject>{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = "";
}
```

ParentObject has some set of fields.
While logging this object I get empty object in the logs "MyObject()".

However, if I replace `@Data` with `@Getter` and `@Setter` then it works perfectly and the object is getting printed along with its properties.
As per my understanding `@Data` in a way a collection for all getter, setter, hashcode etc. methods. Is there a way to disable specific methods to identify which of these methods is causing the problem?

I got the code working with `@Getter`/`@Setter` but looking for an understanding as to why `@Data` caused this problem.

Comment: As a first step to debug this, you should probably be using Lombok's "Delombok" functionality, which allows you to turn code that has lombok annotations into its "vanilla representation". That will allow you to take a better look at what's happening.

In general, it is very likely not a good idea to be extending ArrayList in the way that you are - are you sure you really need a type that extends ArrayList? You could always instead implement the List interface, and delegate the calls to an arraylist that is part of your object.

Comment: Please pay heed to the issues pointed out in the above comment.

Comment: Further, to point out the exact issue. @Data generates a `toString` for the `MyObject` class. If you use `@Getter` and `@Setter` instead, you do not get a `toString` in `MyObject`. Hence, the `toString` inherited from `ArrayList` is used. The `ArrayList`'s `toString` method calls `toString` on each of the element it stores. Hence, you see the fields in the `ParentObject`.  I hope this clears up things.

Anyways, extending `ArrayList` is a red herring and almost always a bad idea. Don't do it.

Comment: Thanks. This helps. It is legacy code but will discuss to have it updated.